# Number formating, spaces every 3 digits

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

How can I change number without formating and decimal values (like: 125478521478) to string that has spaces every 3 digits (like: 24 148 147), it would have to convert ~100 of those numbers so I'm looking for efficient solution.

Comment: In  a spreadsheet?  An uiApp application?  Please specify the context....there is a gs method called utilities.formatString  that is designed to do such things...see the docs here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities

Comment: @Sergeinsas I saw that one but I could not manage to create spaces using it, only changed the decimal number count. Might have been error on my part though as I'm quite new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script should help you. You can run this script in a loop for all the numbers.
Considering `125478521478` as your number for demonstration. The code shall be as follows -

```
var yourNumber = "125478521478";
yourNumber  = yourNumber.toString().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ");
```

Hope it helps!