# Number formating spaces every 3 digits

Tags: c#

Hello i want to do a text with where is changing number . but when its big number you cant read it . so i want to make it every 3 digits will space. 
For example **32874123** will be **32 874 123** . Thank you . Ive seen it there: [Number formating, spaces every 3 digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24306464/number-formating-spaces-every-3-digits) but its in javascript .

I have trying to do it with lenght or something but it didnt work for me . 
Thank you for all your help .

Comment: `...but its in javascript` Does that invalidate the concept?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

You can format it with commas, and replace the commas with spaces

```
var result = inputNumber.ToString("N0",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Replace(',', ' ');
```

Comment: @LaggKing In some cultures, `.` is the separator.

Comment: In some cultures it's a `.`

Comment: you guys are right, would adding CultureInfo.InvariantCulture ensure it defaults to the comma?

Comment: @TomiKordos this should not be the answer you use, its not a great answer compared to the much better one you have from Ron.  There is a reason this is sitting at -3 and the other is +7.

Answer (score 15):

If you want to do it the "right" way, use a new `NumberFormatInfo`:

```
var ni = new CultureInfo(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name).NumberFormat;

ni.NumberDecimalDigits = 0;             //Keep the ".00" from appearing
ni.NumberGroupSeparator = " ";          //Set the group separator to a space
ni.NumberGroupSizes = new int[] { 3 };  //Groups of 3 digits

var dig = 123456789;

Console.WriteLine(dig.ToString("N", ni));
```

Results in:

```
123 456 789
```

#### [Try it out here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PihncF)

Answer (score 1):

I know you already have an answer, but I thought I'd throw this out there. You could create an extension method that does this, which would simplify things a little when you want to use it (you can just type the number and then type `.ToStringWithSpaces()`).

For example:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string ToStringWithSpaces(this int number)
    {
        var numStr = number.ToString();
        var len = numStr.Length;
        var result = new StringBuilder();
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            if (i > 0 && i % 3 == 0) result.Insert(0, " ");
            result.Insert(0, numStr[len - 1 - i]);
        }
        return result.ToString();
    }
}
```

Then, in use:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var bigNumber = int.MaxValue;

    Console.WriteLine(123.ToStringWithSpaces());
    Console.WriteLine(1234.ToStringWithSpaces());
    Console.WriteLine(12345.ToStringWithSpaces());
    Console.WriteLine(123456.ToStringWithSpaces());
    Console.WriteLine(1234567.ToStringWithSpaces());
    Console.WriteLine(32874123.ToStringWithSpaces());
    Console.WriteLine(bigNumber.ToStringWithSpaces());

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone!! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image]

---

One nice thing about this approach is that you could also add the insertion position and separator string as arguments (with default values). This way, you could customize the output.

Here's a modified version:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string ToCustomString(this int number, 
        int position = 3, string separator = " ")
    {
        var numStr = number.ToString();
        var len = numStr.Length;
        var result = new StringBuilder();
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            if (i > 0 && i % position == 0) result.Insert(0, separator);
            result.Insert(0, numStr[len - 1 - i]);
        }
        return result.ToString();
    }
}
```

Now we can display the number with the default values (a space every three characters), or we could customize it. For example, if the number was being written in the middle of some text (**or, even worse, if you were writing two numbers next to each other separated by a space**), spaces might make it harder to read. In that case we might use dashes.

Here's an example:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var bigNumber = int.MaxValue;

    Console.WriteLine(bigNumber.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(bigNumber.ToCustomString());
    Console.WriteLine(bigNumber.ToCustomString(2, "-"));
    Console.WriteLine(bigNumber.ToCustomString(5, " < *_* > "));

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone!! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image]